# Why this code alerts "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The below mention is my source code and i just get json data from the external url and i just try to alert the name of the guy whose that data is belongs to. But it doesnt work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Fetch json example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>

  <body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/4944823?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {

        var a = (JSON.stringify(res.items[0]));
        alert(a.display_name);
            }
        });

});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I just alert the a `alert(a);`it alway gives the raw data but when i try to alert something like a.display_name or something else it always returns undefined. What is the actually the problem.

Comment: remove `JSON.stringify()`, You don't need it

Comment: If you're trying to convert a JSON to a JS Object use `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro, API already return JSON so `JSON.parse` is not required, notice `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Thanks you it fixes my issue

Answer (score 2):

The response is already parsed when `dataType: 'json'` so this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/4944823?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
              alert(res.items[0].display_name);
            }
        });

});
```

If you'd need to parse a string as json you should use JSON.parse(string), JSON.stringify(json) is used to convert a json to string.